# PHP PDO não roda UPDATE na mesma pagina do SELECT

Tags: php, pdo

Problema: fazer UPDATE funcionar
Questão: Está correto o script?
Solicitação: Identificar o motivo de não fazer o UPDATE e gerar erro.
Erro: Notice: Undefined variable: db  e   Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
Observação: em outro projeto uso o mesmo update e select e funciona na mesma página
Agradecimento: a todos que puder dar uma luz
Código:

```
<?php
include ("conexao.php");
$email = $_POST['email'];
// Checando se o email informado está cadastrado
$resultad = $db->select_pdo("SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE email= '{$email}'");
if ( count($resultad) ) {
foreach($resultad as $row) {
  if($row['12'] == 0);
}  
}else {
    echo "<div class='inf' align='center'>Este email não está cadastrado em nosso banco de dados.</div><br /><br />";

            exit();

        }

// gerar senha aleatória
$recupera  = $_POST['recupera'];
switch ($recupera){

case "recupera" :

    recupera_senha($email);
}

function recupera_senha($email){

function geraSenha(){

            //caracteres que serão usados na senha randomica
            $chars = 'abcdxyswzABCDZYWSZ0123456789';
            //ve o tamnha maximo que a senha pode ter
            $max = strlen($chars) - 1;
            //declara $senha
            $senha = null;

            //loop que gerará a senha de 8 caracteres
            for($i=0;$i < 8; $i++){

                    $senha .= $chars{mt_rand(0,$max)};

            }
            return $senha;          
    }

    $senha_randomica   =  geraSenha();
    $senha = md5($senha_randomica);


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: NOME - Webmaster<EMAIL@DOMINIO.com.br>"; 

$subject = "Sua nova senha SITE";

$message = "Olá, redefinimos sua senha.<br /><br />
           <strong>Nova Senha</strong>: {$senha_randomica}<br /><br />

           <a href='http://LINK/formulario_login.html'>

http://LINK/formulario_login.html

           </a><br /><br />
           Obrigado!<br /><br />
           Webmaster<br /><br /><br />

           Esta é uma mensagem automática, por favor não responda!";

            mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

            echo "Sua nova senha foi gerada com sucesso e enviada para o seu email!<br      />
                 Por favor verifique seu email!<br /><br />";



            //Atualiza cadastro
            $db->select_pdo("SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE email ='{$email}'");
            $data=array ($email);
            $db->update_pdo('UPDATE pessoa SET `senha_pessoa`=?', $data);
}
?>
```

conexão-------------

```
<?php
ob_start();
Class PDODatabase{
private $host = 'localhost';
private $user = 'USER';
private $pass= 'SENHA';
private $dbname = 'BASE';
private $DBH;
private $STH;
public $err;
public $result;

//funcao publica para pegar ultimo registro
public function lastInsertId(){
return $this->DBH->lastInsertId();
}
//connect to database and make error system
public function __construct(){
//Connct to database
try{
$this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->user,     $this->pass);
$this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}
catch(PDOException $err){
echo $this->err->getMessage();
}
}
//close database connection
public function  close_pdo(){
$this->DBH = null;
}
//delete query from database
public function  delete_pdo($sql){
try{
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$this->STH->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $err){
return "When we try to delete your query we get this message" . $err->getMessage();
}
}
//update query from database
public function  update_pdo($sql,$data){
try{
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$this->STH->execute($data);
return true;
}
catch(PDOException $err){
return "When we try to delete your query we get this message" . $err->getMessage();
}
}
//insert into database
public function  insert_pdo($sql,$data){
try{
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$this->STH->execute($data);
}
catch(PDOException $err){
return "When we try to delete your query we get this message" . $err->getMessage();
}
}
//select from database
public function  select_pdo($sql){
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$this->STH->execute();
return $this->result = $this->STH->fetchAll();
}
//Row count
public function rowCount_pdo($sql)
{
$this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
return   $this->result = $this->STH->rowCount();
}
}
$database = new PDODatabase();
$db =& $database;
//ob_end_flush();
?>
```

---------fim conexao

Comment: Eduardo, você pode [edit] sua questão para deixar ela mais legível.

Comment: Formatação feita, obrigado @gmsantos

Comment: Passe a variável $db para a função.

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é separa a definição `geraSenha()` de dentro de `recupera_senha($email)` ou simplesmente remover `geraSenha()`.

Uma função definida dentro da outra

```
function recupera_senha($email){
function geraSenha(){
```

Pode mudar para:

```
function recupera_senha($email, $db){
  //código ...
  $senha_randomica   =  geraSenha();
 //mais código ...
}

function geraSenha(){
 //código...
 return ....
}
```

Funções apenas enxergam variáveis passadas como argumento na assinatura da função ou criadas dentro dela ou seja uma função não pode acessar uma variável global.

Para corrigir o problema pode fazer desse maneira:

Mude:

```
function recupera_senha($email){
```

Para:

```
function recupera_senha($email, $db){
```

Outra sugestão é no lugar do parâmetro `$db` trocar por uma outra função que retorna a conexão com o banco de dados.

Comment: Dados do arquivo de conexão que estou utilizando acrescentado na pergunta.

Comment: Sua conexão está certa, o que falta é passar ela como parâmetro na função @eduardo correia, :P logo coloco outro exemplo.

Comment: No aguardo @rray, obrigado!

Comment: @EduardoCorreia segue o [exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ubp9-dekk) isso é o que está acontecendo com o seu código, ao a primeira vez vai dar erro é preciso descomentar as linhas comentadas e comentar as não comentadas :P.